# What happened to my inline source control functions when doing a merge in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, version-control

I've been using Visual Studio code to build my Angular applications for a while now. It's great.

However, I seem to have lost a very valuable feature -- inline actions for merging.

According to this:

https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/versioncontrol#_merge-conflicts

it says, "Differences are highlighted and there are inline actions to accept either one or both changes."

I *used* to see the inline actions to accept given changes, but I don't see them anymore.

Am I missing some feature or configuration?  I have scoured the configuration options but can't see anything.

How can I get my inline merge actions back?

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you see ?

Comment: googling lead me to this issue : https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/issues/319 , where some people seem to have a temporary fix : disable then re-enable "Merge conflict > Code lens" and "Editor > Code lens" (see [randallmeeker's comment](https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/issues/319#issuecomment-471221976) in this issue)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  This was what got it back working:  https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/issues/319#issuecomment-431723468

Comment: 4+ years after this question was asked, I just had the same issue for the first time. Pleased to report that disabling and re-enabling the settings mentioned above still fixes the problem.